# Military standard barcode/label software for OS X

Tags: osx, pdf, barcode

I'm looking for software for Mac native that has custom label and barcode generation capability. The formats required for this job are Code 128, and PDF417. The software will have to be able to print to a DYMO LabelWriter 450, Brother P-touch 9500PC, and an HP Laserjet 3015.

The software will be used by warehouse workers of varying PC knowledge and replacing LabelRight software.

Answer (score 1):

[Softmatic BarcodeFactory](https://itunes.apple.com/app/softmatic-barcodefactory/id662720270?mt=12&at=10lvzo&ct=PDF417) seems to provide everything that you need and much more

- PDF417, Aztec, QR Code, Datamatrix
- Code 128 ABC w/ auto-discrimination and  GS1/UCC/EAN
- Generate barcode from spreadsheets (Excel / Numbers)

As for printing, it should work as long as your printer has a driver for OS X.

- [LabelWriter 450 drivers](http://www.dymo.com/en-US/labelwriter-450-label-printer#tabContainer)
- [PT-9500PC drivers](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=9500eus&os=10017)
- [LaserJet 3015 drivers](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=378050&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=219)

Comment: Thank you @adib I will look into the software capabilities to see if it suits my organization's needs.